# how unload scripts in akeneo with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, akeneo

I have next issue. Admin panel have implemented with  akeneo in my project. . When turned between pages, these scripts added to page. How upload (remove) these scripts?
Some page looks:

```
require(
    ['jquery', 'datepicker', 'oro/navigation'],
    function ($, datepicker, Navigation) {
        ...
    }
);
</script>
<form class="form-inline" id="form-search">
  ...
</form>
```

**Edit:** Akeneo version 1.2.0. I want remove excess scripts. I think it's connected with requirejs.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more informations about your problem? What is your akeneo version? What do you want to do, I don't understand "unload" these scripts.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Akeneo version 1.2.0. I want remove scripts odd scripts for my page. Normely, on admin page added scripts, when i i click other page previous scripts not removing and added new script and so on